# Exploding a complex string in PHP

Tags: php

I found this on php.net, and I am asking for a little clarification:

**Example 2 (explode function)**

```
$data = "foo:*:1023:1000::/home/foo:/bin/sh";
list($user, $pass, $uid, $gid, $gecos, $home, $shell) = explode(":", $data);
echo $user; // foo
echo $pass; // *
```

There are two colons in the middle, does that mean that $gecos has no value?

Comment: -1. If you have already recieved a warning you should have known better than to post this one. It's a simple matter of echo $gecos to find out whether it's empty or not

Comment: Haha, that's right, I'm so stupid and haven't thought of that! Thanks~

Answer (score 2):

Your question and confusion are not all that bad, your disclaimer story is!

You can simply print all the output of explode to find out the answer

```
<?php
$data = "foo:*:1023:1000::/home/foo:/bin/sh";
print_r(explode(":", $data));
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => *
    [2] => 1023
    [3] => 1000
    [4] => 
    [5] => /home/foo
    [6] => /bin/sh
)
```

So yes, as you thought, 5th variable in your `list` will have no value because there lies nothing between those colons at that position.

Comment: Lol thank you, I never thought everyone is pokerface here. Didn't intent to disclaim at all.